# Delete/Clear Calendar events with c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an app that uses a .net console application that will run unattended with the scheduled task during the day.  I have been able to insert events no problem.  But  what I want to do is delete events and/or clear the calendar.  I need to use a service account because the program runs unattended.  When I run this code below it gives me a 403 unauthorized error.  I have shared out this calendar to the service account email address.  I get the error on the  service.Calendars.Clear(Calitems[0].Id).Execute(); line.

When I run the clear command from the console it runs but it needs the oauth authorization.  Please tell me I dont have to authenticate to delete/clear calendar events.  Since this program runs unattended, that wouldn't work.

Thanks again for the help.

```
 string keyFilePath = "thekeyfile.p12";
 string serviceAccountEmail = "serviceaccountemail@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "****", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

 ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));
 // Create the service.
 CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
      HttpClientInitializer = credential,
      ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
 });

 var calendarList = service.CalendarList.List().Execute();
 IList<CalendarListEntry> Calitems = calendarList.Items;
 EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(Calitems[0].Id);
 Console.WriteLine("Starting");

 service.Calendars.Clear(Calitems[0].Id).Execute();

 Console.WriteLine("Ending");

 return true;
```

Comment: Are you sending primary calendar name in clear method?? check whether credentials for inserting event and deleting event are same..

Comment: I did double check that the credentials were the same.  That was a good suggestion.  I also send the calendar name as "primary" with the same result.  Is that what you mean by clear?

Comment: Nope "primary" means, you have to give your primary calendar ID

Comment: When I run the example at this link I just type in primary.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear  But I will try it.